# How to force a mobile device to ask for a computer site

Tags: php, android, html

I have a website that is optimized for both mobile and desktop devices. It turns out that on some mobile devices the following error appears:

> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

However if I ask the site for computer it already lets run the site. Is there any way to get the default web site to run on computer version. Or some other 
solution? Thank you.

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 
 charset=ibm866" > <meta name = "viewport" content= "width=device=width, 
 initial-scale=1">
   <title>Meusite</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="width: 100%; 
   text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
    <div style="text-align: center;"><img src="img/vendas.jpg" style="width: 
    100%;" />
    <!--<div style="text-align: center;"><img src="img/mini.JPG" 
     style="width: 100%;" />
        <div style="text-align: center;"><img src="img/miniII.JPG" 
      style="width: 100%;" />-->


    <div style="text-align: right; font-family: Arial;"></div>
    </div>


    <div style="text-align: center;"><br />
    &nbsp;</div>

    <div style="text-align: center;"><a 
     href="http://www.omeusite.pt/1038/omeusite.php"><img alt="" 
     src="img/Meusite.png" style="border: 0px solid ; width: 220px; " />
      </a><br />
    &nbsp;
    <div style="text-align: right;"><a href="tel:932222222"><img alt="" 
      src="img/tel.png" style="border: 0px solid ; width: 61px; height: 
      61px;" /></a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>


<p></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Fix the underlying problem. Why does your application return `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` to mobile user agents?

Comment: Did not realize the question